# GitLab API how to get the last commit? logs_tree?

Tags: gitlab

GitLab API how to get the last commit?

```json
GET /projects/:id/repository/tree

{
    "name": "assets",
    "type": "tree",
    "mode": "040000",
    "id": "6229c43a7e16fcc7e95f923f8ddadb8281d9c6c6"
}
```

How to get `logs_tree`? Last commit?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend follow the spec listed [here](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/commits.html) which says that you can use 
`GET /projects/:id/repository/commits/tree`
to return the following example data:

```json
{
  "id": "6104942438c14ec7bd21c6cd5bd995272b3faff6",
  "short_id": "6104942438c",
  "title": "Sanitize for network graph",
  "author_name": "randx",
  "author_email": "dmitriy.zaporozhets@gmail.com",
  "created_at": "2012-09-20T09:06:12+03:00",
  "message": "Sanitize for network graph",
  "committed_date": "2012-09-20T09:06:12+03:00",
  "authored_date": "2012-09-20T09:06:12+03:00",
  "parent_ids": [
    "ae1d9fb46aa2b07ee9836d49862ec4e2c46fbbba"
  ],
  "status": "running"
}
```

This is the latest commit. In terms of finding `logs_tree` the [full documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/#authentication) may help you.

Comment: this has probably change and not valid

Comment: Invalid answer its throw 404

Answer (score 5):

Since at least version 12.10 GitLab supports pagination.
That's why the call returns only one commit.

```
GET /api/v4/projects/:id/repository/commits?per_page=1
```

Answer (score 3):

At the current version of API we have only one way to solve this problem

```
GET /api/v4/projects/:id/repository/commits
```

The first commit in the array will be the desired one. You can extract it with `jq '.[0]'`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this API.

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/branches/:branch
```

The result of this API includes the latest commit of the branch.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html#get-single-repository-branch