# How to extract this information using git and how to record git status of the container repo and submodules when running ansible-playbook command

Tags: git, ansible

we use a custom git repository layout for our in-house developed roles

```
    roles (git container repo)
    |--some_role_1 (git submodule)
    |--some_role_2 (git submodule)
```

in order for us to have a good trace-ability we would like to have the possibility to log the current commits for each role and the container repo when we run the ansible-playbook command.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you know the `git` commands to use to get this information (e.g., is this question "how do I extract this information with git?", or is this question, "how do I log the output of these git commands?", or is it something else)?

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the new perspective. The question is both then.

Answer (score 1):

### Getting the commits

You can git the current commit id of a git repository like this:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
9520e6c2b699d117caed391cce9e2d79f8b0f0b2
```

Or if you want a little more information, you could instead ask for a
one-line log, which gets you the commit id and the first line of the
commit message:

```
$ git log --oneline -1
9520e6c overcloud: allow for custom xml in baremetal vm definitions
```

You can get the current git commit of each of your submodules with the
`git submodule` command, which by itself produces something like:

```
e1ec52e365a8fbe95c83db5da3046730c4dc39b2 lib/ansible/modules/core (remotes/origin/synchronize-better-error-missing-rsync-31-ge1ec52e)
14a62fb5d6771871654aedb4a36e17cf358785dc lib/ansible/modules/extras (remotes/origin/json-imports-fallback-161-g14a62fb)
```

Or you can get the `--oneline` log output like this:

```
$ git submodule foreach git log --oneline -1
Entering 'lib/ansible/modules/core'
e1ec52e Re-add version_added to fireball docs
Entering 'lib/ansible/modules/extras'
14a62fb Merge pull request #1415 from jtyr/jtyr-yumrepo_params
```

Or maybe a little prettier, something like this:

```
git submodule foreach -q bash -c \
  '(echo -n "${PWD##*/} "; git log --oneline -1 | cat)'
```

Which gets you something like:

```
core e1ec52e Re-add version_added to fireball docs
extras 14a62fb Merge pull request #1415 from jtyr/jtyr-yumrepo_params
```

### Logging this information with Ansible

You can get the output of a command into Ansible with the `register:`
keyword on a task.  For example:

```
- name: get commit of of parent repository                                  
  command: git log --oneline -1
  register: parent_commit                                                   

- name: get commit id of submodules                                         
  command: >
    git submodule foreach -q bash
    -c 'echo -n "${PWD##*/} "; git log --oneline -1'
  register: submodule_commits
```

At this point, we have the output of the first command in
`parent_commit.stdout` and the output of the second command in
`submodule_commits.stdout`.  See [the ansible
documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables)
for more information about the `register` directive.

Now that you have this information in a variable, what can you do with
it?  You could log it using the `debug` module:

```
- debug:
    msg: "Parent repository: {{parent_commit.stdout}}"

- debug:
    msg: "Submodule: {{item}}"
  with_items: "{{submodule_commits.stdout_lines}}"
```

This would get you output along the lines of:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Parent repository: 058208b implement folding of long lines in inventory"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=core e1ec52e Re-add version_added to fireball docs) => {
    "item": "core e1ec52e Re-add version_added to fireball docs", 
    "msg": "Submodule: core e1ec52e Re-add version_added to fireball docs"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=extras 14a62fb Merge pull request #1415 from jtyr/jtyr-yumrepo_params) => {
    "item": "extras 14a62fb Merge pull request #1415 from jtyr/jtyr-yumrepo_params", 
    "msg": "Submodule: extras 14a62fb Merge pull request #1415 from jtyr/jtyr-yumrepo_params"
}
```

Hopefully that's sufficient to get you started.

Comment: Thanks! great start (even a bit later, just found time now)
We are trying to use the 'git rev-parse HEAD' and store that in the targeted host, from time to time we plan get an Ansible docker container checking if the sha is the same as with the latest commit in the gitlab using API's and if not we might propose to the user to update the configuration or even to automate it. We found a way to get the API last commit sha but it needs more work [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483314/gitlab-api-how-to-get-last-commit-logs-tree)